# How to check why QCA DHPrivateKey did not create symetric key

Tags: qt, cryptography

I have program who exchange session key via Diffie-Hellman algorithm, or almost exchange. All action is 2 classes: one receives data and calculates private key, set it to second class, where symmetric key is calculated after receiving public part of DH.
Program is using Qt and QCA.
Private key is stored as widget class member:

```
QCA::DHPrivateKey m_localKey;
```

after receiving public part of other side key (as QByteArray) it calculates symetric key:

```
QCA::Initializer init;
QCA::DLGroup group(prime, p);
QCA::SecureArray remoteKey(m_remoteKey);
QCA::DHPublicKey pk(group, remoteKey);
m_sessionKey = m_localKey.deriveKey(pk);
```

but session key is always empty (m_sessionKey.isEmpty() and m_sessionKey.isNull() are true).
Values are set and they are exchange correct (remote part public key is received as it is),
m_localKey.isNull() and pk.isNull() returns correct values (false).

strange part is that when I run test, it works. Test use same order operations just private keys are created in one class, but logic to get symmetric key is same, and class used for that is same.

My question would be why it could behave different in test and separate programs. And is it possible to get any error/debug information from QCA::DHPrivateKey about what went wrong in `deriveKey()`?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly that code was lost so can't check for sure, but problem probably was in 2 places - transfering/receiving data and too many QCA::Initializer calls.

After set QCA::Initializer in main and [re]writing data exchange code it works.
It's still sad that I don't know how check errors, if such occurs, so if anyone know please share these knowledges.